# Alternative to ROW_NUMBER() on SQL SERVER 2008 to add a correlative field in a query

Tags: sql-server, pagination

I looked in a lot of books, blogs, forums, etc. to find a solution for the following problem, without success.
Basically, we have a query that return "blocks" of records (pagination), and the way it was implemente was with rownum

```
DECLARE @startRow INT
DECLARE @endRow INT
-- @pageIndex  and @pageSize are parameters
SET @startRow = ((@pageIndex - 1) * @pageSize) + 1
SET @endRow = @startRow + @pageSize - 1
Select * from 
(
  select 
    Field1,
    Field2,
    Field3,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Field2 ASC ) AS [ROWNUMBER]
  FROM
    TABLE1
    JOIN TABLE2 ON (some join logic here)
  WHERE  
    (More business logic here)
) as Results
    WHERE
        [ROWNUMBER] BETWEEN @startRow AND @endRow
```

As you can see, the order of the "pages" are based on the correlative that ROWNUMBER return-
Well, a requirement changes asked to order by Field2, who is a alphanumeric code, with the following logic:

-The codes (Field2) with letters, must to be orderer in an alphabetic way
-The codes with ONLY numbers, instead, must to be orderer as numbers

I added the following order by

```
ORDER BY
        CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(Code, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Code), LEN(Code))), 
        LEFT(Code, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Code)-1)
```

And it worked great!! But the problem is, that invalidate the ROW_NUMBER!!
If I put the ROW_NUMBER inside the subquery, SQL SERVER reject it, if I put it outside, it added, but "before the sort", so, when I try to extract the pages, I received a re-order that doesn't follow the original requisition.

I don't know if solve this is possible, I was thinking that maybe there a way to "add" a correlative "after" the sort, or maybe some of you can think in a totally different way to deal with this issue, because in this moment, my head only want to explote :)

Thanks any advance to any help

Comment: you have to duplicate your order by logic into rownumber `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY .... )`

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who have the same problem, I found a solution, and it was very simple: add the order by rules  not in the order by of the query, but in the order by of row_number

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(Code, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Code), LEN(Code))), -- numerical
            LEFT(Code, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Code)-1) ) AS [ROWNUMBER]    -- alphabetical sort ASC )
```

That's all

:)